# Change log file name of teraterm log

Tags: logging, terminal, teraterm

I would like to change the default log file name of teraterm terminal log.
What I would like to do automatically create/append log in a file name like "loggedinhost-teraterm.log"

I found following ini setting for log file.
It also uses `strftime` to format log filename.

```
    ; Default Log file name. You can specify strftime format to here.
    LogDefaultName=teraterm "%d %b %Y" .log
    ; Default path to save the log file.
    LogDefaultPath=
    ; Auto start logging with default log file name.
    LogAutoStart=on
```

I have modified it to include date.

Is there any way to prefix hostname in logfile name

Fox eg,

```
myserver01-teraterm.log
myserver02-teraterm.logfile
myserver03-teraterm.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, and was able to solve my problem by adding &h like below;

`; Default Log file name. You can specify strftime format to here.
LogDefaultName=teraterm &h %d %b %y.log
; Default path to save the log file.
LogDefaultPath=C:\Users\Logs
; Auto start logging with default log file name.
LogAutoStart=on`

Answer (score 1):

https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/menu/setup-additional.html

**"Log" tab**

View log editor

Specify the editor that is used for display log file

**Default log file name(strftime format)**

Specify default log file name. It can include a format of strftime.

```
&h      Host name(or empty when not connecting)
&p      TCP port number(or empty when not connecting, not TCP connection)
&u      Logon user name
%a      Abbreviated weekday name
%A      Full weekday name
%b      Abbreviated month name
%B      Full month name
%c      Date and time representation appropriate for locale
%d      Day of month as decimal number (01 - 31)
%H      Hour in 24-hour format (00 - 23)
%I      Hour in 12-hour format (01 - 12)
%j      Day of year as decimal number (001 - 366)
%m      Month as decimal number (01 - 12)
%M      Minute as decimal number (00 -  59)
%p      Current locale's A.M./P.M. indicator for 12-hour clock
%S      Second as decimal number (00 - 59)
%U      Week of year as decimal number, with Sunday as first day of week (00 - 53)
%w      Weekday as decimal number (0 - 6; Sunday is 0)
%W      Week of year as decimal number, with Monday as first day of week (00 - 53)
%x      Date representation for current locale
%X      Time representation for current locale
%y      Year without century, as decimal number (00 - 99)
%Y      Year with century, as decimal number
%z, %Z  Either the time-zone name or time zone abbreviation, depending on registry settings;
    no characters if time zone is unknown
%%      Percent sign
```

example:

teraterm-&h-%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S.log